# Solr 3.6.2 spellcheck multi-word phrase: how to get collations without ignored stopwords?

Tags: solr, spell-checking, stop-words

I'm having a problem with the Solr 3.6.2 default (field based) spellchecker configured with query time parameters

- spellcheck.onlyMorePopular=true
- spellcheck.count=5
- spellcheck.collate=true
- spellcheck.maxCollations=5
- spellcheck.maxCollationTries=5

on a field type which has a solr.StopFilterFactory filter on its analyzers.

The suggestion phase works as intended :

- the indexed field does not contain any stopword
- no suggestion is provided for a given stopword

**But the resulting collation always contains the ignored stopwords**, which I don't want: I'd prefer a raw suggestion of combined terms over something which looks like a "sort of" natural language answer.
For instance, searching for "handfum of perries", I'd prefer "handful berry" over "handful of berry".

I don't think that the stopwords excluded from spellchecking suggestions because of the field query analyzer are "marked" for preservation like the [official documentation](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent#Collate_Results) goes about other query elements :

> Note that the non-spellcheckable terms such as those for range
>   queries, prefix queries etc. are detected and excluded for
>   spellchecking. Such non-spellcheckable terms are preserved in the
>   collated output so that the original query can be run again, as is.

It seems two solutions would be

- either having a [custom query converter](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent#Implementing_a_QueryConverter) so the stopwords are ignored right from the start: not sure it is possible in 3.6.2
- or having a custom spellchecker that would not try to find any suggestion for a stopword (or would always suggest an "empty" string), without messing up the collation process

Am I missing something ?

Regards